# Which widget of a VerticalPanel has been clicked in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a post widget in a blog application which are stored in a VerticalPanel.

I want to know if it's possible to handle the click at the VerticalPanel and get the Post Widget which has been clicked?

EDIT: I'm also thinking about wrapping each Post in a custom Cell using this http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html so I can later paginate my posts. Is that a good idea? Is there a standard way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: So you have one parent `VerticalPanel` in which you list many `PostWidget` children, or one `VerticalPanel` per `PostWidget` child?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have one `VerticalPanel` where I store many `PostWidget` children. So I'm wondering is there a gwt way to have pagination and async loading to display the `PostWidget`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you'd be better off using a [`CellList`](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) with a [Custom Cell](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html) describing each post. Two reasons for this:

1. GWT's Cell Widgets are all capable of using a `ListDataProvider` (or better yet, an [`AsyncDataProvider`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html)) out of the box. You'd end up writing a great deal of code to get where they are.
2. You can easily learn how to implement both a `AsyncDataProvider` and a `CellList` with a pager in a very short time from the [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) examples or other sources.